# RSA long value not enough

Tags: encryption, rsa, long-integer, gmp

I'm working on a RSA ecrypt-decrypt assignment. I'm having a problem with the decryption part. I get the encrypted number correctly ( compared to a solved example to check if it was correct ), but on decryption, it is wrong.

instead of doing Decrypt= fmod(pow(cipher,d), N), I tried just seeing what the value was coming for pow(cipher,d).  And that's where the error is. Both the cipher and d are positive numbers but the result is coming is a big negative number.

I tried looking up, found some solutions saying to try long long. I tried that too and didn't work.

Is there any way to solve this without using external libraries or writing a library of my own ?

Comment: Are you using a "bignum" type library (a library that can manipulate integers of any magnitude)? The algorithm to compute c^d mod n is *not* simply mod(pow(c, d), n). It ensures that the intermediate result never exceeds the modulus, even though c^d will generally be far far larger.

Comment: See ["Right-to-left binary method".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method)

Comment: I'm not using the gmp library. this is for an assignment and I'm not too sure if it'll be accepted if I use the library. Is there any way around it ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to implement the pseudo-code in the Wikipedia section using fixed-size integer types, as long as your modulus is small enough.

Comment: Could you cobble up some answer from the comments erickson?